# How to ask for License File while creating a setup of Win Application in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, setup-project

I am creating a setup of a application where I want user to select a license file provided by us. During installation, this file should be copied and placed in installation folder.

I can find away to put license code but could not a find how to ask for license file.

Can someone please help me.

Thanks
Dev

Comment: Why would you ask for a license file if the file is *already there*? Maybe the app could ask for such a file if it doesn't find it where it's supposed to be.

Comment: There should be ample resources on file dialogs if you do a search.

Comment: @Jimi, No, file does not already exist. The file will be different for each system on which application will be installed. This file is node locked license file.

But yes, your suggestion makes sense to make software to ask for a file when it does not find it.

Answer (score 0):

You want user to select a license file when installing the application. You can refer to the following steps:

- Right click on your setup project
- Select view option
- Select User interferce

Then you can see the interface below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEVGC.png)

- Right click on start
- Select add Dialog
- Select License Agreement
- Right click on License Agreement
- Select Properties window and you can select your license file here

Comment: Thanks Theobald, 

Seems we misunderstood what I meant by license file. I am not referring to license agreement.

I want to select 'node locked license file'. The file that contains license information in encrypted format which is read by software to check if system have valid license.

Thanks